# How to authenticate same user in two different AWS regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have two services, sitting in **two separate regions** on their own, that have the same authentification solution, with AWS Cognito and each of those instances has federated in their user pool, the same identity provider.
In front of the application, there is an API Gateway, that should grant access to the desired service.

The user could have the following scenario: goes to authenticate in `region1`, gets his token, and then the API Gateway from `region1` will permit his access based on it. Can this token be used to access a service in `region2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Cognito is configured in `region1`, if you set the Cognito pool from `region1` as authorizer for the API Gateway in `region2`, that should allow this API Gateway to authenticate users in Cognito. It also works cross-account.

Hopefully the docs help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html